# How can I make my Django rest API run along side my react app on a custom domain HTTPS server?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, csrf-token

I was wondering if it would be possible to run my Django rest API along side my react app on a custom domain HTTPS server.

Currently I have my website on a google cloud VM with a custom domain attached to it via the CloudFlare service. The issue that I am currently facing is that I cannot set the csrftoken cookie on my browser since I would be trying to access my API on port 8000 (Unsafe) while my page is on HTTP or even HTTPS on a different domain.

What should I do in this situation? What would be my best option?

I have tried setting the `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE` to None but it requires me to set `Secure` as well but once I do this I end up with a similar problem where I cannot access the token as my API is not on a secure server.

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail. Is your React App a static only site? Does it use React-router, does it SSR, etc. Why use port 8000 for your API? you should simply set your endpoint to be `https://customdomain.whatev/api` while the static React site is served from `https://customdomain.whatev`

Comment: I do use React-router with CSR I just use Django with the rest API framework. I use port 8000 since I cannot expose the same port to both Django and React I believe. I am using docker and WSGI, ASGI to configure Django. I always thought of doing exactly what you mentioned about having my API on the same domain but I have been beating my head against a wall for hours trying to figure out how I can do that with the Rest API. Thank you very much.

Comment: `npm run build` - copy the contents of the build folder to the document root of your http server. The `index.html` file will be served @ port 80. You'll need to set up your server to redirect any requests other than `/` or `/api/*` to `index.html`. Your server should be set to direct any requests for your `api` routes to your Django instance. Alternatively, you can package your React App up with your Django Docker container and use the `proxy` property in the `package.json` file of the React app to proxy all requests to the Django server set up as detailed.

Comment: Some of these may help you get where you want to be: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+react+docker